# Local Windows Service to Make WebAPI Calls and Connect Securely

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I am trying to design a local windows service that makes a call to a website API to see what tasks it needs to run, execute the tasks on a local server, then return the results to the website.  I have the local tasks to run, the WebAPI ready to be consumed, but I am trying to figure out how to securely connect the two applications.

I have thought about creating a windows service app login only, but I am not sure that is the right way since I have also read about web services (I only have the WebAPI controllers programmed).  The website is ASP.Net 4.7.2.  Any guidance as to how to go about connecting these would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought/considered of (arguably) a simpler approach - e.g. `console apps` (essentially executables - `exe`) orchestrated by Windows Scheduler (scheduled tasks)?

Comment: I have but I might need to run more often like ping every 5 minutes and felt task scheduler, that can be messed up or fail to run, would result in more setup. Still need to figure out how best to connect these two.

Comment: IMHO, whatever caveats you have thought of for Windows Scheduler will be the same for the service _you'll write_. IMHO, if it needs to be "always on" then its a service (e.g. watch folder for file changes). If it's a known _schedule_ I defer to a _scheduler_ + handling options (failure, retry, kill, etc). Other solutions like [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/index.html) come into play if there is no access to OS/system (only in code).